# Robust way to implement "bottom navigation tab bar"

Tags: android, tabs

The effect is like this:

[image]

I have investigated some methods.

Somebody use `radiogroup`, somebody use `tabhost`.

What is the simplest way?

Is there any other way?

Comment: Switch to iOS? Why not follow [the design guide lines](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html)?

Comment: Nope. Because this style is widely used on android app and I think it is more natural (I can put 'back' or 'search' bar on top).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really what google  recommends in there  [Design Guidelines for tabs](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html), if you still want to use it, i think TabHost is the perfect way.For more see [How to align your TabHost at the bottom of the screen](http://envyandroid.com/archives/326/align-tabhost-at-bottom)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: This is good. But how can I add the TabHost inside an ActionBarActivity?

Comment: "It is not really what google recommends" you have right! But, if a customer want the a mirror app in android based on ios bottom nav menu is a requirement

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this link](http://viewpagerindicator.com) which contains library and sample codes for each type of tab (i.e circle, underline, etc)

Using this library, You can implement different type of tab format. Your work is just import this library into your app.

And, [Samples](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/sample) will help you to understand the different tab format.

All the Best!